# Emulate index method with generator

Tags: python, filter, python-3.x

The `filter` function in Python 3 allows us to return elements from an `Iterable` that match some arbitrary criteria defined in a filter function.  I'd like to be able to do something similar, except instead of returning elements which satisfy the criteria, I'd like to return the *index* of the elements. (similar to the `index` method for `list` objects)

```
>>> stuff = ("foo", "bar", "baz")
>>> f = filter(lambda x: x == "baz", stuff)
>>> [e for e in f]
['baz'] # Here I want the integer 2 because "baz" is at index 2
```

Of course, I realize in this trivial example I could just say:

```
stuff = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
index = stuff.index("baz")
```

But the point is, I want to be able to get an index using arbitrary filter functions and arbitrary Iterables (not just lists!)

Is there a convenient way to do this without handrolling a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i,x in enumerate(stuff) if x == "baz"]
[2]
```

or a generator expression:

```
>>> gen = (i for i,x in enumerate(stuff) if x == "baz")
>>> list(gen)
[2]
```